# LinearLayout inside the second column of a GridLayout overflows the screen when width set to match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-gridlayout

I am trying to place a `LinearLayout` inside the second column of a parent `GridLayout`.I want a `textView` in the first column and the linear layout in the second.

The problem is that when I set the `LinearLayout`'s with property to `match_parent`, the linear layout expands with a width greater than the remaining space in the column and it and the `GridLayout`overflow the screen as shown below in the picture.

I am assuming the the `LinearLayout`'s parent is not the GridLayout's second column therefore the match_parent key sets the width to the wisth of the whole screen(also applies to height with a property of match_parent)

I am looking for a way that the column becomes the `LinearLayout`'s parent so that it fills the rest of the screen in front of the `textview`

and I want to use the grid layout on purpose because of its advantages in design.I am also new to android so any help would be appriciated.

here's the layout code just in case :

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:columnCount="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"></LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />
</GridLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that I was trying to fill the remaining horizontal space with `android:layout_width` and setting it to `match_parent`.The problem with this approach is that with match parent, I am setting the width of the layout with its parent's(the grid layout) width which is as big as the whole screen, therefore it overflows the devices screen.

I should have set `android:layout_gravity` to `fill_horizontal` in order to achieve my goal